# How to move between screens with a condition (if...)

Tags: objective-c, ios

Suppose i have a Register Class,
and by a (UIButton) "Go" button i check all of the fields that the user entered, all of the fields are UITextField.
I made a action for that "Go" button in the Register class to move to the next ViewController by a push, also in the action function i check the user input (for example bad email x@xxx)
and if the user entered a bad input i dont want to move to the new screen.
So, to make a long story short, My question is how i make a condition to move between the screens.
"if the user entered a correct input so make the move... else stay"
I dont want to make another button to check the correctness of the form and then, first the user will press the check button then the second button to send the form.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
-(BOOL) validateField:(UITextField *)field{

// perform your validation and return YES or NO

return YES;
}
```

in your button action

```
BOOL validated = NO;

if ([self validateField:textfield1]){

validated = YES;.

}else{
return; // or your error message
}
if ([self validateField:textfield2]){

validated = YES;
}else{

return;// or your error message

}
```

and so on..

```
if (validated){
[self pushViewController:yourcontroller]
}
```

Comment: i tried to do a return; in my action button but it still make the move

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use a `BOOL`. You could for example set this BOOL to `false` within the `viewDidLoad` method. If all your checks you do with the input data are passed correctly you set this `BOOL` to `true`. Now you can use this value either to push the next view controller or not to push it.
For example

```
if (theBOOL) {
    // push the next view controller
} else {
    // display a message on the current view controller to recheck the input data
}
```